# Compile error while Archiving in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, frameworks

I know this is a common problem but I couldn't find any specific solution for my problem so can't solve it. I can successfully build the app and run it. However, when I'm trying to archive, It gives error. I'm using a framework and It gives error for it.
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Try to set Build architectures to Standard instead of another one in build setting and compile again .

Comment: I can't find it. Where it is?

Comment: Select target > build setting > type Architecture > set standard

Comment: It is standard already.(Standard architectures(armv7, arm64)

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35763006/3901620

Answer (score 0):

If "Hero" is your own framework try the following:

1. Make sure that all the framework classes you use in the main project are marked as public:

   ```
   public class SampleClass...
   ```
2. Add -ObjC to linker flags in your build settings (see attached screenshot). This will allow you to use extensions declared in the framework.
   [image]