# (Class) is unavailable: cannot find swift declaration for this class ONLY for iPhone <= 5 simulator, Generic iOS Device and Release Build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, audiokit

I understand that many similiar questions have been asked in the past - however, none of them exactly applies to my situation.

I am using the AudioKit framework in my app. I added the framework by copying the framework into the app directory and adding it to embedded binaries. It runs perfectly on the iOS simulators after the iPhone 5 simulator (i.e. 5S plus). However, when building for: earlier simulators; Generic iOS Device; and my device (which is an iPhone SE) I get the error `(Class) is unavailable: cannot find swift declaration for this class` where (Class) is every single AudioKit class in my code.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851550/myclass-is-unavailable-cannot-find-swift-declaration-for-this-class-release-b) I've checked the framework's `Modules` folder and the only files there are `x86_64.swiftdoc` and `x86_64.swiftmodule`. As I understand, to build for a real iOS device I need an `arm64.swiftmodule`. However, I cannot figure out how to create this file/where to find it.

The linked question would suggest that I need to change the framework's deployment target, but I can't figure out how to change it (or even where the framework's deployment target is stated).

I have tried creating a new xCode project, building it from the start for Generic iOS device, then adding the AudioKit framework - but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally decided to give up trying to make it work. Used Carthage instead - works perfectly. If anyone else has this issue - just use Carthage.