# AudioKit xcode10

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

```
var delay: AKVariableDelay!
var delayMixer: AKDryWetMixer!
var reverb: AKCostelloReverb!
var reverbMixer: AKDryWetMixer!
var booster: AKBooster!
var tracker : AKAmplitudeTracker!
```

> 'AKVariableDelay' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for
>   this class
>
> AKDryWetMixer' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this
>   class
>
> 'AKCostelloReverb' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for
>   this class
>
> 'AKDryWetMixer' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this
>   class
>
> 'AKBooster' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this
>   class
>
> 'AKAmplitudeTracker' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for
>   this class

I receive these errors but I am able to build and to run the project, i think that something is wrong with my project settings and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851550/myclass-is-unavailable-cannot-find-swift-declaration-for-this-class-release-b)

Comment: yes thank you , problem with .swiftmodule files , i have reused the build_frameworks script another time and it worked.