# Framework can be imported but class name not found swift

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a fat framework file which i created using lipo

Performing:

```
lipo -info CocoaMQTT.framework/CocoaMQTT
```

gives:

```
Architectures in the fat file: CocoaMQTT.framework/CocoaMQTT are: x86_64 arm64
```

but when I import it into xcode project I can only run the application in simulator. On device it cannot find the class name.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post an error example you get when trying to run the app on a device?

Comment: 'CocoaMQTTDelegate' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this protocol

Comment: Could it be this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851550/myclass-is-unavailable-cannot-find-swift-declaration-for-this-class-release-b

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it did not work both contains arm64 and I tried several time to clean/remove derivedData/rebuild and it did not work

Comment: What is the device you are trying to run the app?

Comment: iPad air, but even build it on Generic Device gives the same error